# Generate random coordinates of points on a circle

Tags: random, geometry, coordinates

I have to write a code where I write a random number, it should give me the number of random points with coordinates and after these points to draw the corresponding circle. I really need help because I do not even know how to start writting.

I find this code on Stackoverflow:

```
import random
import math

# radius of the circle
circle_r = 10
# center of the circle (x, y)
circle_x = 5
circle_y = 7

# random angle
alpha = 2 * math.pi * random.random()
# random radius
r = circle_r * math.sqrt(random.random())
# calculating coordinates
x = r * math.cos(alpha) + circle_x
y = r * math.sin(alpha) + circle_y

print("Random point", (x, y))
```

How can I change this code that I could get random multiple points for random circle?

Comment: simply use `for` or any other loop

Comment: For random points on a pre-defined circle I suggest using polar coordinates with a fixed radius. You may have to convert polar to X-Y coordinates depending on the wording of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [vectorized](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/) solution using NumPy (I removed the `math` library). Random 100 alphas (`size` parameter) are samples from a uniform distribution.

I renamed `circle_` to `center_`

```py
import random

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# radius of the circle
circle_r = 10
# center of the circle (x, y)
center_x = 5
center_y = 7

# random angle
alpha = 2 * np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, size=100)
# random radius
r = circle_r * np.sqrt(random.random())
# calculating coordinates
x = r * np.cos(alpha) + center_x
y = r * np.sin(alpha) + center_y

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()

print("Random point", (x, y))
```

[image]